# Converting rotations in Unreal to achieve smooth movement

Tags: rotation, unreal-engine4

I'm trying to fix a rotation error that I'm experiencing in Unreal. I have an animated car and the wheel is going crazy as it's gaining speed. I suspect this has something to do with euler rotations. Is there a way to check this and eventually to convert them to radians or quaternions?

Comment: Need more information than "is going crazy" and "suspect this has something to do with euler rotations". Do you have any code or blueprints to share?  What do you mean by "check this"? Yes, there are ways to represent rotations in unreal engine 4 as quaternions. Do you mean to ask how you can do that? In C++ or blueprint?

Comment: I mean if there's a way to check if an object is using Euler or quaternion rotations. Anyway, I've found a solution which works partially. In the sequencer there's an option to check, which is called 'use quaternion rotation'. This makes me think that the default rotations of imported fbx are Euler. By 'partially' I mean that the problem goes away when I render the animation via the sequencer but stays the same in the editor. By crazy I mean: my wheel should rotate smoothly(I guess around its two local axis) instead it rotates unpredictably in all axis, resulting in a wrong movement.